# SQL Server Query optimization : too many self inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

I am currently trying to improve a SQL query on SQL Server.

My working table looks like this :

**CAT_HISTORY**

```
DATE        ID          CATEGORY
----------- ----------- -----------
20121201    A           1
20121201    A           1
20121201    B           1
20121201    C           2
20131201    A           2
20131201    B           4
20131201    C           3
20141201    A           3
20141201    B           2
20141201    B           2
20141201    C           1
```

And my objective is to retrieve the history of their category.
So far I am doing this :

```
 SELECT   A.DATE
         ,COUNT(DISTINCT A.ID) AS NB_CLIENTS
         ,A.CATEGORY           AS STARTING_CAT
         ,B.CATOGORY           AS ENDING_CAT

FROM CAT_HISTORY A
INNER JOIN CAT_HISTORY B 
ON (
     A.ID= B.ID
 AND
 ( 
    ( 
          A.DATE = 20121201
      AND B.DATE = 20131201 
    )
  OR  
    (
          A.DATE  = 20131201
      AND B.DATE  = 20141201
    )

  WHERE A.DATE>= 20121201 AND B.DATE<= 20141201
  GROUP BY A.DATE, A.CATEGORY,B.CATEGORY
  ORDER BY A.DATE, A.CATEGORY,B.CATEGORY
```

And the result is :

```
DATE_KEY   STARTING_CAT ENDING_CAT     NB_CLIENTS 
-----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
20121201     1            2            1
20121201     1            4            1
20121201     2            3            1
20131201     2            3            1
20131201     4            2            1
20131201     2            3            1
```

But the thing is that I have way more dates, and I add an OR for every date (about 15 distinct dates), and I have loads of users. Which means the query sometimes takes up to 15min to get results.

I believe I am being brutal on my INNER JOINs, and that there probably is a more elegant and efficient way of getting the expected result.

My final objective is to get a Sankey to see the evolutions from one category to another through time, and I need the amount of users that moved from a category to another between to dates.

Using Gordon Linoff's answer, it worked nicely but is counting duplicates

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE, CATEGORY,NEXT_CATEGORY, COUNT(*) AS NB_CLIENTS
FROM (  
        SELECT DISTINCT CH.*, LEAD(CATEGORY) OVER (PARTITION BY CH.ID ORDER BY DATE) AS NEXT_CATEGORY
        FROM CAT_HISTORY CH 
        ) CH
        WHERE  NEXT_CATEGORY IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY DATE, CATEGORY,NEXT_CATEGORY
```

Example :
Expected

```
DATE_KEY     STARTING_CAT ENDING_CAT   NB_CLIENTS 
-----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
20121201     1            2            1
20121201     1            4            1
20121201     2            3            1
20131201     2            3            1
20131201     4            2            1
20131201     2            3            1
```

With your solution :

```
DATE_KEY     STARTING_CAT ENDING_CAT   NB_CLIENTS 
-----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
20121201     1            1            1
20121201     1            2            1
20121201     1            4            1
20121201     2            3            1
20131201     2            3            1
20131201     4            2            1
20131201     2            3            1
20141201     2            2            1
```

Last edit :

I managed to find a workaround :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT DATE, CATEGORY,NEXT_CATEGORY, COUNT(*) AS NB_CLIENTS
    FROM (  
            SELECT DISTINCT CH.*, LEAD(CATEGORY) OVER (PARTITION BY CH.ID ORDER BY DATE) AS NEXT_CATEGORY
            FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM CAT_HISTORY) CH 
            ) CH
            WHERE  NEXT_CATEGORY IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY DATE, CATEGORY,NEXT_CATEGORY
```

Comment: I update my answer, you have issue because I was not added sample data with structure. One thing I don't understand about your output result , how NB_clients have 5 ,1,1,13 data based on your input data, just explain. so give better answer.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to make it work. And I have update my answer with corresponding data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see pair-wise changes, then use `lead()` rather than fixed dates.  In SQL Server 2012+, you can do:

```
select date, category, next_category, count(*)
from (select ch.*,
             lead(category) over (partition by id order by date) as next_category
      from cat_history ch
     ) ch
group by date, category, next_category;
```

In earlier versions of SQL Server, you can use similar logic with a correlated subquery or `apply`.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, it works nice but I now have issues with the fact that the working table has duplicates.
I have edited my post with the details.

Comment: @AxelR . . . You should actually ask another question, rather than changing a question hat already has answers.

Comment: My bad, I didn't want to spam questions :/

Answer (score 0):

Please check this, I replace `date field` to `datefield`.

```
declare @t table(datefield date , id varchar(10) , category int )

insert into @t values
(cast( '20121201' as date) , 'A', 1),
(cast( '20121201' as date) , 'B', 1),
(cast( '20121201' as date) , 'C', 2),
(cast( '20131201' as date) , 'A', 2),
(cast( '20131201' as date) , 'B', 4),
(cast( '20131201' as date) , 'C', 3),
(cast( '20141201' as date) , 'A', 3),
(cast( '20141201' as date) , 'B', 2),
(cast( '20141201' as date) , 'C', 1)

SELECT   A.datefield
         ,COUNT(DISTINCT A.ID) AS NB_CLIENTS
         ,A.CATEGORY           AS STARTING_CAT
         ,isnull(B.CATEGORY ,0)       AS ENDING_CAT
FROM @T A
left JOIN @T B 
ON 
    ( 
        A.ID= B.ID   AND 
        ( b.datefield =  dateadd( yy, 1 , a.datefield ) ) 
    )
 -- WHERE A.datefield>= '20121201' AND ( B.datefield<= '20141201' or B.datefield is null)
  GROUP BY A.datefield, A.CATEGORY,B.CATEGORY
  ORDER BY A.datefield, A.CATEGORY,B.CATEGORY
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am having trouble using it as the datefield is an integer on my side and the query returns an arithmetic overflow when executing it.

Comment: Why on earth are you storing dates as an integer, that is a very poor practice.

Comment: We are receiving dates from different timezones and as we would like to avoid date conversions, we decided to insert their raw value as integer.